# CSS on first letter of <p> only not <blockquote><p>

Tags: css, nested

Please help me out here, I've created this jsfiddle to make it clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/yvesvanlaer/2r3Cp/

The first letter is also different in a deeper level

I only want it to be on the first P (not in the blockquote).

Thank you so much.

```
<div about="/news/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-elit" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" class="ds-1col node node-news view-mode-full clearfix">
  <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item even" property="dc:title">
              <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
                <p>
                    Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
                </p>
                <blockquote>
                    <p>
                        Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need only the immediate descendant of `.field-item`, so add that in there with `>`:

```
.view-mode-full .field-name-body .field-item > p:first-child:first-letter {
    float: left;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/2r3Cp/6/)